# Spawn subprocess that expects console input without blocking?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am trying to do a CVS login from Python by calling the cvs.exe process.
When calling cvs.exe by hand, it prints a message to the console and then waits for the user to input the password.

When calling it with subprocess.Popen, I've noticed that the call blocks. The code is

```
subprocess.Popen(cvscmd, shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I assume that it blocks because it's waiting for input, but my expectation was that calling Popen would return immediately and then I could call subprocess.communicate() to input the actual password. How can I achieve this behaviour and avoid blocking on Popen?

OS: Windows XP
Python: 2.6
cvs.exe: 1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the `shell=True` part. Your shell has nothing to do with it. Using `shell=True`  is a common cause of trouble.
- Use a list of parameters for cmd.

Example:

```
cmd = ['cvs', 
       '-d:pserver:anonymous@bayonne.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/bayonne', 
       'login']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This won't block on my system (my script continues executing).
However since cvs reads the password directly from the terminal (not from standard input or output) you **can't** just write the password to the subprocess' stdin.

What you could do is pass the password as part of the CVSROOT specification instead, like this:

```
:pserver:<user>[:<passwd>]@<server>:/<path>
```

I.e. a function to login to a sourceforge project:

```
import subprocess

def login_to_sourceforge_cvs(project, username='anonymous', password=''):
    host = '%s.cvs.sourceforge.net' % project
    path = '/cvsroot/%s' % project
    cmd = ['cvs', 
           '-d:pserver:%s:%s@%s:%s' % (username, password, host, path), 
           'login']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
    return p
```

This works for me. Calling

```
login_to_sourceforge_cvs('bayonne')
```

Will log in anonymously to the bayonne project's cvs.

Comment: Password as part of CVSROOT seems like a better idea, but passing the password makes cvs.exe think that the username is actually "user:password"!
e.g: typing cvs -d :pserver:user:pass@server:path at the command line tries to do a log in for "user:pass" and it's still asking for a password

Comment: @Razvan: My version of CVS seems to work as I said. Maybe you have a modified version? Where did you get your cvs from? Can you upgrade? Have you tried my example code?

Comment: nosklo, I tried removing shell=True and passing the command line as a list, but that didn't work because of the cvs.exe behaviour. 
I took your advice and redownloaded cvs.exe from ftp.gnu.org, because the binary I had was downloaded from another site. It worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are automating external programs that need input - like password - your best bet would probably be to use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect).

Comment: But you cannot use pexpect on Windows system. Yes, there is a port called wexpect, but I couldn't make it work. Seems like it's still under development.